# How to merge Primary object with child objects using and ID reference in Parent to each child

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a primary parent collection (Projects) and 2 child collections stored as arrays with objects.

### Projects

```
const projects = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Logo and Branding for Iron Kettle",
      skills: [
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09f",
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f062"
      ],
      solutions: [
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09e",
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f077"
      ],
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efcb",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f0af"
    },
    {
      name: "Snow shoot for media company",
      skills: [
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f072",
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f062"
      ],
      solutions": [
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09e",
        "579b150756ea2dba79c1f071",
      ],
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efcb",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f06a"
    }
  ],
  count: 12,
  limit: 100,
  offset: 0,
  total: 12
};
```

#### Skills

```
const skills = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Logo Design",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efdf",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09f"
    },
    {
      name: "Brand Research",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efdf",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f072"
    },
    {
      name: "Graphic Design",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efdf",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f062"
    }
  ],
  count: 13,
  limit: 100,
  offset: 0,
  total: 13
};
```

#### Solutions

```
const solutions = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Location research",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1eff3",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09e"
    },
    {
      name: "Complete photo shoot",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1eff3",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f071"
    },
    {
      name: "Competition Analysis",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1eff3",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f077"
    }
  ],
  count: 19,
  limit: 100,
  offset: 0,
  total: 19
};
```

I need to return a new projects array with the skills and solutions id's populated with the actual object from the relevant array.

This would be the end result of one item the new array.

```
{
  name: "Logo and Branding for Iron Kettle",
  skills: [
    {
        name: "Logo Design",
        _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efdf",
        _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09f"
    },
    {
      name: "Graphic Design",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efdf",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f062"
    }
  ],
  solutions: [
    {
      name: "Location research",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1eff3",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f09e"
    },
    {
      name: "Competition Analysis",
      _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1eff3",
      _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f077"
    }
  ],
  _cid: "579b150756ea2dba79c1efcb",
  _id: "579b150756ea2dba79c1f0af"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
projects.items.map(i => ({
    ...i,
    skills: i.skills.map(s => skills.items.find(skill => skill._id === s)),
    solutions: i.solutions.map(s => solutions.items.find(solution => solution._id === s))
}));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! You can see it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fire-q3prr